# How to execute multiple test suite parallel?

Tags: selenium, docker, jenkins, parallel-execution

I have test a suite for 5 different stores (UK,US,FR,IN,PT) of a web application. and there are around 250 test cases. After deployment i need execute the test suite for all these store and it takes around 6 hrs for one store. I have to initiate execution in sequence.

I'm planning to execute them parallel. I have a separate desktop and I've configured Jenkins on that, I tried, triggering 2 job at a time, unfortunately my system get crashed.

Is there any efficient way to do this either using Jenkins or other (I've heard about docker container) ?

Comment: Which framework are you using to execute the tests?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Grid is a pretty decent, plain vanilla way to run tests in parallel especially if you already using Selenium as your automation framework.

Documentation: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp

If your needs require, there are other options to look at including containerized solutions (as you've mentioned about Docker):

- Selenoid (https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid)
- Zalenium (https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/)

Both solutions above build on top of Selenium Grid so they're worth checking out as well.

Selenoid uses docker containers which is a cleaner way of running tests (as the containers gets destroyed and created for each test-case.

Personally, I've used Selenium Grid for years and it's about to handle my suite of about 450 test-cases.